# Build Failed in blackberry phonegap application

Tags: blackberry, cordova

When i am trying to build new blackberry phonegap application using the instructions of phonegap site. I got an error like

```
Buildfile: build.xml
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
Target "create" does not exist in the project "Build and Deploy a PhoneGap BlackBerry WebWorks Project".
```

By running the command prompt. 
Can any one give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs due to missing **project.properties** file.

Remember you are in right directory in command prompt.
Also if problem exist download phonegap archive again and replace the project.properties file in you directory with the new file available in ***phonegap>blackberry>sample>***